# In BigCommerce how do you remove/update a product from the cart with a link

Tags: bigcommerce

How can I get more info on doing actions via links? eg updating/removing/adding to the cart, variants, etc etc

https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/How-can-I-add-a-product-to-the-cart-with-a-link

This is has limited info.
Click to open rich previewsupport.bigcommerce.com

Comment: So there actually is a link to remove a product from the cart, however you would need to use JavaScript to determine that product's hash, which is unique every time it is added to the cart. Specifically, that link looks something like: `https://store.com/cart.php?action=remove&item=582d0b6980aad`
Where `582d0b6980aad` is the hash for that product. You can determine this by making an Ajax call to cart.php (the call has to be made on an HTTPS page), and parsing the HTML for the link found in the `remove` button or the `x` button that would be clicked to remove the product.

Comment: Any updates to products in the cart have to be done with a POST request, which again requires that you know the product hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to support further actions with links as BigCommerce hasn't added this functionality